# Is there a small Linux that installs within Windows?

Tags: windows, linux

Is there a Linux like [Wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) that could be installed in a 360MB partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If don't need persistance - that is to say, needing your linux install to be consistant across boots, you could likely use [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to boot something like slitaz or tinycore - and use ntfs-3g in them to manipulate the windows partition in question

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of small Linuxes, there is even a version that fits on a floppy disk.
[DSL](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) (Damn Small Linux) would in my opinion be a good solution, its very small and still has a lot of features like a full and usable desktop.

what exactly are you trying to accomplish?
if you need to run linux binaries in your windows you could use colinux (runs a Linux kernel in windows) or mingw (kinda Linux-ish environment with all the bin tools for windows)

Comment: I'm looking for a smaller version of wubi. Which would let me boot into a linux distro without partitioning so i could mount a partion and copy/delete files to it

Comment: I just tested out the Damn small linux and it wont work for me for some reason.

Comment: do you want to mount a linux partition from windows? depending on the filesystem there are other solutions for that, e.g. an ext2 driver for windows

Comment: no i want to mount a windows partion from linux...It doesent really have to be linux. but i need to be able to boot from the boot menu to do so.

Comment: Because my BIOS has a password on it and i have forgotten it

Comment: You don't need any disk space if you boot from a Linux live CD like Ubuntu or Partition Magic.  Either will enable you to access the Windows partition.  Unless that BIOS password is preventing you from booting from CD or USB.

Comment: It is preventing me

Comment: The easiest thing to would be to clear the CMOS, honestly. Pull the battery out for 15 minutes, or move the jumper.